# Using only CSS, is there a way to change a specific image's color to white on black?

Tags: css, image, user-interface, firefox, colors

I use CSS to create dark theme versions of some popular websites.

One of the issues I run into is images like these:

[image: black foreground reply button]
https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/reply_black_20dp.png

[image: black foreground vertical dots button]
https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png

Sites use `background-image` to display these images.

When I apply `filter: invert(1)` to these images, I get a white-on-white image in Firefox.

Is there a way, using only CSS, to make these images display as white on black?  It doesn't matter to me if you use `filter` or another technique.

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply a white background and then do your filter:

```css
img {
  background: #fff;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLpPT.png">
```

And with background:

```css
img {
  background: #fff;
}
.box {
  background:
   url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLpPT.png) 0 0/20px 20px no-repeat,
   #fff;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```